# Running load() within Skylark macro

Tags: tensorflow, bazel

If your project depends on TensorFlow it is recommended that you add...

`load("//tensorflow:workspace.bzl", "tf_workspace")
tf_workspace()`

...to your `WORKSPACE` file, which will load all of TF's dependencies.

However, if you look at TensorFlow's `workspace.bzl` file...
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/workspace.bzl

you can see that it depends on rules from `@io_bazel_rules_closure`. This means you also have to define this `@io_bazel_rules_closure` rule in your `WORKSPACE` file and keep it in sync with TensorFlow, even if you don't need it anywhere else in your project.

Is there a way to add the `load()` command somehow/somewhere into the `tf_workspace()` macro?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure that io_bazel_rules_closure must be kept in sync? The [rules defined there](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_closure) are unlikely to change.

Comment: Its more terrible that any Bazel project that depends on TF needs to add io_bazel_rules_closure to their own WORKSPACE file even if their project doesnt use it. That seems confusing to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no way to add this rule in `tf_workspace()`, since the skylark rule `tf_workspace()` defined in  https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/workspace.bzl needs to load `@io_bazel_rules_closure`.

There are basically two ways to make this work

- either the tensorflow project redefines its rules so that it only uses internal rules or native rules.
- or bazel is able to load the workspace of a dependency (and I assume load all the transitive dependencies too). This is a hard problem and is tracked in [#1943](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/1943).

Comment: No this doesnt answer my question. I want to load io_bazel_rules_closure within the tf_workspace macro. I understand that tf_workspace requires io_bazel_rules_closure. It would be great for projects that depend on TF to only need to add tf_workspace() to their workspace. The have to also include the io_bazel_rules_closure rule in their WORKSPACE file even if they dont need it for their own project

Comment: I agree and understand. Edited my answer becomes this comment box was too  small.